# Inequality Question about Converging Sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence, summation

This is from the UPenn prelim questions. http://hans.math.upenn.edu/amcs/AMCS/prelims/prelim_review.pdf

(I asked the question before, and there was no answer, so I am asking it again..
I'm not sure if this is allowed or not in this forum, and if this violates the rules, 
I will delete the post).

We have the following series

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^n}{1-x^n}$$

It's easy to show that the series converges for all x in the interval (-1, 1) The hard part (At least for me) was to show that for x in [0, 1), we have the following inequality:

$$(1-x)^2 f(x) \geq x$$

I tried the following: when $x=0,(1−x)2f(x)=0$, and $x=0$, and see how the value of the derivative of $(1−x)2f(x)$ compares with 1 (which is the derivative of x), for $0<x<1$, then if that derivative is greater than or equal to 1 for 0

Could someone help me with this? Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

sequences-and-series

Comment: it is completely *not* against the rules. you are allowed to ask of course.

Comment: Is there a typo somewhere in your formula or am I missing something? If I insert $x=1/2$ the denominators tend to $1$, so you basically have $\sum n/2$, which does not converge.

Comment: @thomas: typo found (using source document) and fixed.

Comment: Did you try subtracting $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ from the terms of the series?(This is just a guess,I haven't tried it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\large f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(1-x^n)}$

Applying a Taylor expansion, we have

$\large f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n(1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{nk})\geq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n$

as $0\leq x < 1$

The sum

$\large \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}=x\frac{d}{dx}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n)=x\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{1-x})=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

where we note that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ is a sum to infinity of a Geometric progression, so that it equals $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

So we have

$\large f(x)\geq \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$

Multiplying both sides by $(1-x)^2$, which is a positive value, thus keeping the same direction of the inequality, we have

$\large (1-x)^2f(x)\geq x$